# A complex complex integral operation

Tags: complex-geometry, integration

This question mainly asks about the integral of complex numbers. This question originates from the optical properties of the axicon angle.$\lambda, f,R,ρ_{0},k$
are a constant.

$$m(r,\varphi)=\frac{1}{i\lambda f}\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi } {e^{-i\frac{2\pi \rho}{\rho_{0}}}}{e^{-i\frac{kr\rho }{f}\cos(\phi -\varphi)}}\rho d\rho d\phi$$

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Personally, I would not use variants $\phi$ and $\varphi$ at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

First integrate over $\phi$,
$$\frac{1}{i\lambda f}\int_{0}^{2\pi } {e^{-i\frac{2\pi \rho}{\rho_{0}}}}{e^{-i\frac{kr\rho }{f}\cos(\phi -\varphi)}}\rho d\phi=\frac{2 \pi  \rho}{i\lambda f} e^{-\frac{2 i \pi  \rho}{\rho_0}} J_0\left(\frac{k r \rho}{f}\right).$$
The integral over $\rho$ is a hypergeometric function, resulting in
$$m(r,\varphi)=\frac{2 \pi  r}{i\lambda f} R e^{-\frac{2 i \pi  R}{\rho_0}} \, _1F_2\left(\tfrac{1}{2};1,\tfrac{3}{2};-\frac{k^2 r^2 R^2}{4 f^2}\right).$$
There is no dependence on $\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up the confusion. I have never understood hypergeometric functions before. Can you provide some important intermediate processes and general forms of hypergeometric function $_{1}F_{2}$?

Comment: you can find a collection of formulas at the Wolfram [site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/) ; there is not much to understand here, you may want to rely on Wolfram Alpha to implement the desired relationships.

Comment: "rely on Wolfram Alpha" ... Mistakes in integral Wolfram formulas are not infrequent. I myself have encountered several of them. So, in such cases a proof is needed.

Comment: The ultimate purpose of this formula is to solve the following problem: For a two-dimensional space function, what should be done in the frequency domain in order to obtain the angular or radial differential in the spatial domain? But it doesn't work. So what should I do to solve the problem？